# Ruby XML Iteration RSS Feed

Tags: ruby

I am using the following code to get the Item from the Rss feed but it only gives me the first item. How can I get all the items:

```
root.elements["channel/item"].each do |item|

    titles << item.text 

  end
```

UPDATED:

```
titles = [] 

  # go through the collection and prints the title

  root.elements["channel/item"].each do |item|

    titles << item.text 

  end

  puts titles
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with that code.
Ensure you properly set titles = [] before trying to append elements. Also you should provide more details about which library you are using. I assume this is REXML, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**: I just noticed you call elements[]. Change the code to

```
root.elements.each("channel/item") do |item|
  titles << item.text 
end
```

Comment: That did not print anything!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
root.elements.each("channel/item") do |item|

    #puts item

    titles << item.text("title")

  end

  puts titles
```